# Stanley Enumerative Combinatorics proposition 1.3.7 third proof question on fact

Tags: combinatorics

I was looking at the third proof of proposition 1.3.7 found in Stanley's Enumerative combinatorics book. He states that the summation in the image below counts the number of pairs (S,f) s.t f satisfies the condition said also said in the image. I don't see why is this. I'll appreciate it if someone clarifies that fact.

[image]

Comment: Think about this; given a particular subset $S$, say $S=\{1,3,4,7\}$, how many functions $f:S\to [n-1]$ satisfy $f(i)\le i$ for all $i\in S$? You need to choose $f(1),f(3),f(4)$ and $f(7)$. There are ___ choices for $f(1)$, there are ___ choices for $f(3)$, etc. Fill in those blanks, and determine how the resulting product relates to $\sum_{1\le a_1<a_2<\dots<a_{n-k}\le n-1} a_1\cdots a_{n-k}$.